# PostgresException: 23503: update or delete on table violates foreign key constraint

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, action-filter

When I want to insert to log table in OnActionExecuted (action filter) after endpoint executed I get below error:

```
 Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23503: update or delete on table "Roles" violates foreign key constraint "FK_RoleId" on table "Users"
```

But I dont insert any of these table and a table has no foreign key column which I want to insert data.
My insert comment is like this:

```
  ctx.LogResponses.Add(log);
  ctx.SaveChanges();
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't used the context elsewhere to insert? Is there a trigger on the `LogResponses` table?

Comment: @Charlieface no tigger on the table. I used context to insert data another table which there is no fk between them  before this method

Comment: Which other table? `Roles`?

Comment: no roles, I have a table name requests

Comment: @Charlieface and there is no any fk between them

Comment: Clearly *something* is causing an extra insert to `Roles`. Either it's the client app, or a trigger in the database. It may be some kind of logon trigger (does Postgres have that?) go over everything with a fine tooth comb